# ng-disabled doesn't update even if form validity is populated

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I created a directive that check if an input is valid based on some criteria. In this form I have a button that is `ng-disabled="form.$invalid"`. The problem is that, even if it seems like the valid state is populated, my button is not enabled when my custom directive change the validity state of the input.

Here is a simple example:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fooController">
    <form name="fooForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="foo" foo>
      <input type="submit" value="send" ng-disabled="fooForm.$invalid">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (CoffeeScript):

```
app = angular.module 'app', []

app.directive 'foo', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    require: 'ngModel'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, controller) ->
      element.bind 'keyup', ->
        if controller.$viewValue isnt 'foo'
          controller.$setValidity 'foo', false
        else
          controller.$setValidity 'foo', true

app.controller 'fooController', ($scope) ->
  $scope.foo = 'bar'
```

In short, this directive check if the input's value === 'foo'. If it's not it sets the validity 'foo' to false, otherwise to true.

Here is a jsfiddle (javascript) : http://jsfiddle.net/owwLwqbk/

I found a solution involving $apply: http://jsfiddle.net/owwLwqbk/1/

But I wonder if there's not an other, a better way of doing it? Isn't the state supposed to populate?

Answer (score 1):

The jqLite event handler runs outside the context of Angular, that's why you needed the `scope.$apply()` before it would work.

Another option is to use a watch...

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    scope.$watch(function () { 
        return controller.$viewValue;
    }, function (newValue) {
        controller.$setValidity('foo', newValue === 'foo');
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra0zqvqw/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I thought using the "$setValidity", an angular method, would help to populate the new validity state. I like the way you're doing it, clear syntax but I'm a bit worried about performance issue. Isn't best to avoid using $watch when possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below

```js
var app;

app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        if (val == "bar") {
          ctrl.$setValidity('foo', true);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('foo', false);

        }
      });





    }
  };
});

app.controller('fooController', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
});
```

```css
.ng-invalid-foo {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fooController">
    [Only "bar" is valid value] <br/>
    <form name="fooForm">
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="foo" foo="">
      <input type="submit" value="send" ng-disabled="fooForm.$invalid" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For now I'm planning to go with your solution, seems more "native". However, in my real case I am checking if the input's value is the same as an other input's value (password repetition ;)). Is there a way to apply your solution to this particular case? Here is an example that reflects my real case: http://jsfiddle.net/1nm3gc6w/1/ I guess I have to $watch the reference value to do something like applying the validators but is that possible?

Comment: @Zhouzi yes you need to $watch reference value because user can change password after inputing confirmation password please see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/6vtjg7to/2/